# C# conversão de um private void para public void

Tags: c#

Olá a todos eu percisava de saber como posso converter este codigo para `public void`. O Visual Studio acusa erro na variável **e**.

**Mensagem de erro:** *"The name 'e' does not exist in the current context"*

Eu limitei-me a fazer `ctrl+c` e `ctrl+v` de:

```
private void TextDisplay_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

Para:

```
public void Detect()
```

Abaixo o corpo do meu método:

```
if (e.KeyChar == 49 || e.KeyChar == 50 || e.KeyChar == 51 || e.KeyChar == 52 || e.KeyChar == 53 || e.KeyChar == 54 || e.KeyChar == 55 || e.KeyChar == 56 || e.KeyChar == 57 || e.KeyChar == 58)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + e.KeyChar.ToString();
        }

        //Detetor da tecla Equal
        if (e.KeyChar == 61)
        {
            Equal();
        }

        //Detetor da tecla Multi
        if (e.KeyChar == 42)
        {
            Multi();
        }

        //Detetor da tecla Plus
        if (e.KeyChar == 43)
        {
            Plus();
        }

        //Detetor da tecla Divisão
        if (e.KeyChar == 47)
        {
            Divisão();
        }

        //Detetor da tecla  less
        if (e.KeyChar == 45)
        {
            Less();
        }

        //DetetoR da tecla backspace
        if (e.KeyChar == 8)
        {
            if (TextDisplay.Text == "")
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                if (TextDisplay.Text.Length == 1)
                {
                    TextDisplay.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text.Substring(0, TextDisplay.Text.Length - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        //Detetor da tecla enter
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            Equal();
        }

        //Detetor da tecla Esc
        if (e.KeyChar == 27)
        {
            Clear();
        }
```

Comment: A mudança que está informando na pergunta não deve causar nenhum problema. De qualquer forma só com esse trecho não é possível identificar o que ocorre. Coloque mais detalhes sobre o erro (mensagem, linha) e outros trechos relevantes.

Comment: @bigown eu limitaime a fazer ctrl c ctrl v do codigo acima de `private void TextDisplay_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)` para `public void Detect()` fiz ctrl s e apareceu o erro acima

Comment: coloque public void Detect(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

Comment: @PabloVargas Obrigado podes por isso como resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ao trocar a visibilidade e nome do método, você deve manter os parâmetros também.
Ficando da seguinte forma

```
public void Detect(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa entender o problema: O corpo do seu método com a assinatura `private void TextDisplay_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)` usa a variável "**e**" para detectar as teclas selecionadas e fazer algumas comparações dentro desse método.

Quando você mudou a assinatura no método para `public void Detect()` essa variável deixou de existir, por esse motivo ocorreu o erro *"The name 'e' does not exist in the current context"*.

Para solucionar esse erro você precisa declarar os mesmos parâmetros:

```
public void Detect(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```